# Git LFS to store database migration history

Tags: git, github, database-migration, flyway, git-lfs

I have a git repository that contains the database migrations scripts history. Those files become immutable as soon as they are executed. (We use Flyway to apply migrations, which are frequent).

The good benefit from using git in this purpose, is to allow code reviews between coders, before altering the database state.

However, I am not comfortable with having history code versioned on git as the files won't change after.

**example:**

```
commit 1: migration_1.sql
commit 2: migration_1.sql migration_2.sql
commit 3: migration_1.sql migration_2.sql migration_3.sql
commit n: migration_1.sql      ...             ...         migration_n.sql
```

My need is to have the ability to review code on git, but only store it on a filesystem without versioning it.

I think of git LFS (large file system) ! Does it do the job? is there some pitfalls to be aware of ?

Or, is there another ways to manage migrations and code reviews ?

Comment: Git LFS is intended for big files such as binaries. Your files are text files and don't take up much space. The fact that they will not be changed does not prevent you from storing them in Git. In fact, Git LFS does not prevent you from changing the files either. Hence, just use Git for those files.

Comment: I see ! you're right. My need is just to review the code on a branch and activate a CI.CD that put the code on a storage service like S3 or Google Cloud Storage. But no need to have it on master .

Comment: Hello, I'd like to understand more about why you think it's a bad idea to version your migration scripts? Of course with Flyway they should never change once deployed. However version controlling your scripts is still really useful. For instance, without version control, if someone does accidentally make a change to an applied migration, you have no way to revert back to the correct script.

Comment: In a way, it is similar to writing logs in git. You end up with a huge folder with immutable scripts. nobody wants to modify it, but we may want to check on it to understand last changes.